# Mark Parameter of WCF service Operation as Required

Tags: wcf, datacontract

I have the following ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = Constants.NAMESPACE)]
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    LoginResult Login(LoginData data);
}

[DataContract(Namespace = Constants.NAMESPACE)]
public class LoginData
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 2)]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a new Request with Soap UI the Request shows this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://namepsace.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:Login>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ws:data>
            <ws:SupplierName>?</ws:SupplierName>
            <ws:Token>?</ws:Token>
         </ws:data>
      </ws:Login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I cannot find the reason why `<!--Optional:-->` is above the data element.

The above code did exactly as an answer suggested in [How to specify a parameter of an OperationContract as required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406559/how-to-specify-a-parameter-of-an-operationcontract-as-required)

What do I need to do to make the data parameter required?

Comment: You mean `<!--Optional:-->`? Or `''`? I don't see a `''`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF: is there an attribute to make parameters in the OperationContract required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836534/wcf-is-there-an-attribute-to-make-parameters-in-the-operationcontract-required)

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836534/wcf-is-there-an-attribute-to-make-parameters-in-the-operationcontract-required) is what you can use, i came across this one while searching answer to this question

Comment: Might have been better suited as a duplicate flagging and comment.