# WCF: is there an attribute to make parameters in the OperationContract required?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, soapui, datamember, operationcontract

I use `[DataMember(IsRequired=true)]` to make the DataContract properties required. There doesn't seem to be some IsRequired for the OperationContract parameters. How do I make them required and not allow null?

The parameter in of OperationContract appears to be optional in SoapUI tool. Though this must never be optional or null.

**WCF Interface:**

```
[OperationContract]
IsClientUpdateRequiredResult IsClientUpdateRequired(IsClientUpdateRequiredInput versie);

...

[DataContract]
public class IsClientUpdateRequiredInput
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public string clientName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 0)]
    public int major { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public int minor { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 2)]
    public int build { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 3)]
    public int revision { get; set; }
}
```

**soapUI request template:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:pir="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PirIS.Web.WCF.InputClasses">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:IsClientUpdateRequired>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:versie>
            <pir:clientName>?</pir:clientName>
            <pir:major>?</pir:major>
            <pir:minor>?</pir:minor>
            <pir:build>?</pir:build>
            <pir:revision>?</pir:revision>
         </tem:versie>
      </tem:IsClientUpdateRequired>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it can't be done using default WCF. There exist a few workarounds:

- A custom [`RequiredParametersBehavior`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3436039/266143) attribute
- Using the [Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664356%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) from the Enterprise Library and [associate a ruleset to your method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664526%28v=pandp.50%29)

You can however implement a FaultContract and throw a fault when the input parameter is null.

Comment: Thanks. Just wish MS had taken care of this in WCF.

Answer (score 1):

No. Just like any regular method, you'll need to check whether reference type parameters have a value or are `null`.

Just apply your normal defensive programming patterns, checking reference types before accessing their properties.

Comment: True. Always expect the unexpected.