# Preventing List of null object in WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, datacontract

In a Wcf service I have the following `ServiceContract`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFooBarService
{ 
    [OperationContract]
    bool SetFooBar(FooBar fb);
}

[DataContract]
public class FooBar 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ExternalId;
    [DataMember]
    public string Something;
    [DataMember]
    public List<Foo> Foos;
    [DataMember]
    public List<Bar> Bars;
}
```

I want to prevent The consumer of the Web Service from sending me List of null Foo/Bar Object.
Is there any annotation to enforce this rules?

Comment: [No, but there are workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836534/wcf-is-there-an-attribute-to-make-parameters-in-the-operationcontract-required)

Comment: Well unfortunatly it's not a dupe, as here I don't care if he send me Foos just that this list of Foo is not a brunch of Null. It's not about been required.

Comment: Can't you just throw a FaultException if it's null? You can't stop the client from sending a null value.

Comment: I will just check and ignore the null as I can't ask them to handle an exception. Well Lets close it as dupe as answer there will be fit.